# Need help on calculating path integral

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Evaluate the folowing path integrals $\int_{c}fds$ and the following are given:

$f(x,y,z) = \frac{x+y}{y+z}$ $\quad$ $c(t)=(t,\frac{2}{3}t^{3/2},t)$

I tried and then got stuck at this step. I'm not sure what trick I could use to continue from there.

$\int\frac{2t\sqrt{2+t}}{\frac{2}{3}t^{2/3}+t}dt$
= $\int\frac{2\sqrt{2+t}}{\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{t}+1}dt$
=6$\int\frac{\sqrt{2+t}}{2\sqrt{t}+3}dt$

A little hint will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think $\;0\le t\le 1\;$ , right? These are things that must be told.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

$$c'(t)=\left(t,\,\frac23t^{3/2},\,t\right)\implies \left\|c'(t)\right\|=\sqrt{1+t+1}=\sqrt{t+2}$$

and our integral is

$$\int_0^1\frac{t+\frac23t^{3/2}}{\frac23t^{3/2}+t}\cdot\sqrt{t+2}\,dt=\int_0^1\sqrt{t+2}\,dt=\left.\frac23(t+2)^{3/2}\right|_0^1=$$

$$=\frac23\left(3^{3/2}-2^{3/2}\right)=2\sqrt3-\frac{4\sqrt2}3$$

Comment: Can't believe I've made such simple mistake!!! I should go back to kindergarten!!!! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @WeiShanNg Welcome to the "Oh, dear! Did I really do that?" club. I'm founding president. :)